# Python - multiprocess improvement beyond value of cpu.count()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I achieved a multiprocess script to improve an image analysis. It works well and currently i try to define the best number of processes in terms of time. 
As expeced when i increase the processes and time decreases but it is the case beyond the value of cpu.count() too. So I dont understand i thought that beyond this latter my time increases again...is there an explanation?

A piece of my code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
import multiprocessing 
import glob as glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import gc
import os
from PIL import Image
from skimage import exposure
import cv2 


Path_input = "E:\\test\\raw\\"
Path_output = "E:\\test\\"

Img_list = glob.glob((Path_input + 'Test_*.tif' ))[:]
size_y,size_x = io.imread(Img_list[0]).shape

#Function for the multi process
def Ajustement(x):
    #image reading
    img = plt.imread(Img_list[x])

    #create a CLAHE object
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    cl1 = clahe.apply(img_rescale.astype(np.uint16))    

    cv2.imwrite(Path_output+ '\\Ajusted' + "%05d" % x + '.tif',cl1) 

    return 'Ajustement OK!'


#create strings list of process
cpu_max = 10
list = ['Process_']*cpu_max
list_process =[]
counter = 1
for u in list:
    list_process.append(list[counter-1]+np.str(counter))
    counter = counter+1

get_timer = time.clock if sys.platform == "win32" else time.time

time_store = []
time_process = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    range_adjusted = np.arange(0,len(Img_list),cpu_max)
    m=0
    for m in range(0,100,1): #loop for obtain a mean time for the process
        gc.collect()
        print m
        timer = get_timer()  # time measuring starts now
        for i in range_adjusted:
            o = 0
            for item in list_process[:cpu_max]: #process creation
                globals()[item] = Process(name ='worker1', target=Normalization_and_ajustement, args=(i+o,))
                o=o+1               
            o = 0
            for item in list_process[:cpu_max]: #process start
                globals()[item].start() 
                o=o+1               
            o = 0
            for item in list_process[:cpu_max]: #process join
                globals()[item].join()  
                o=o+1   

            if i == range_adjusted.max():
                print("Normalization and Equalization finished")

                timer = get_timer() - timer  # get delta time as soon as it finishes
                time_store.append(timer)
                time_process.append(timer/cpu_max)

                np.savetxt(Path_output + 'time_tot_normalization.txt',time_store)
                np.savetxt(Path_output + 'time_process_normalization.txt',time_process)

                print("\tTotal: {:.2f} seconds".format(timer))
                print("\tAvg. per process: {:.2f} seconds".format(timer/cpu_max))
        m=m+1
```

It is Intel Xeon E5-2630v4 at 2.2GHz with 2 sockets of 20 cores. The cpu.count() gives 40 and here some tests :
40 processes : 322 sec\
80 processes : 311 sec\
200 processes : 306 sec\
500 processes : 295 sec\
750 processes : 311 sec

Comment: Can you post the actual value of cpu.count(), how many cores you actually have, and the run times you have experienced?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you can reduce the code in the question down to something more minimal... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry it is done

Comment: Ah cool... but also, would be good if you can adjust+minimise the code so it's runnable by potential answerers.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers you post don't show a tremendous improvement for higher numbers of processes, but...

... My suspicion is that the call to `imread` is a factor. Each call is blocking, but for some of its run time it would be waiting on data from disk, and so not be using much cpu time. During this time, the core(s) would spend more time on other processes. Overall runtime is reduced because the amount of time core(s) are unused due to waiting on data from disk is reduced.